# Input format display

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

Here is my input type date

```
<input style="background:transparent;color:white !important;" class="col-xs-6" type="date" name="date">
```

On desktop when I select a date the format is displayed like this: 12/01/2016 but on mobile is something like: Jan 12, 2016. What can I do to keep on mobile the format with slash?

Comment: **[Well, you can't!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)** Good if you use customized `datepicker`

Comment: [Here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/nov/08/html5-input-typedate-formatting-issues) is an interesting article about this problem.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao any solution or library?

Comment: There are hundreds of 'em. Search for something like **javascript datepicker plugins**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao yeahhh I saw a lot of plugins and I can custom how I want but is not opening the default datepicker from phone

Comment: We might need to see your complete code then.. A separate detailed question with relevant code and your efforts on implementing that would be a great stuff to look on..